# Retaining/hardcoding data in Python

Tags: python

I would like to create something like a permanent storage using Python. What I mean is that I will have some variables coming into my code, and every time I execute my script it might be a different input. Let's imagine I am reading some website that is updating in real time. I want to be able to create a permanent storage that will hold on to the information (internalize it). So that when I get back to my script the next day and run it again, I will still have that internalized data available and it will not get re-set unless I specify so. Is that possible in Python? What should I be looking for? Any modules that do that? I really have no idea where to get started with this.

Comment: What's wrong with outputting to a file?

Comment: Your question is a bit broad. In short: you persist data by writing it to a permanent medium, such as a disk. You can append to a file or use a database - there are a lot of possibilities, and, what will work for you will depend on your use case, which I miss a bit in your question.

Comment: You should take a look at the [chapter about data persistence in the standard library documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/persistence.html) or about the [JSON module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html).

Comment: @mkrieger1, Great link, but why not point to the [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/persistence.html) version?

Comment: Because the Python 2.7 version was above the Python 3 version in the Google results...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no notion of an **image** as smalltalk had it (only heard, never worked with it) in standard python.

Depending on your actual use-case, I can see several approaches:

- use configuration-files, reading on start and writing them in intervals.
- `pickle` your relevant data-structures explicitly, and restore whatever graph of objects you have.
- use stackless python, which allows to serialize interpreter state.